# File[] can not handle multiple files

Tags: java, file

I want to read multiple files from multiple directories. So far my program can read multiple files only until certain limit.

```
 public void filesTobeCollected(String validpath) throws Exception {
    this.folder = new File(validpath);
    //  this.file = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] fileEntry = folder.listFiles();
    System.out.println("directory path" + fileEntry.length);

    /*****File upload read****/

    for (int i = 0; i < fileEntry.length; i++) {

        /*this line weeds out other directories/folders*/
        if (fileEntry[i].exists()) {

            file.add(String.valueOf(fileEntry[i]));
          }
      }
    }
```

and I send value directories through this function,

```
  public List<String> filesTobeTested(ArrayList<String> file) throws   
  Exception {
   Set<String> test = new HashSet<>();
    test.add("src/test/resources/gfd");
    test.add("src/test/resources/rds");
    test.add("src/test/resources/oiu");
    //test.add("src/test/resources/pol");

    System.out.println("directory path 2" + test);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        for (Iterator<String> it = test.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            String f = it.next();
            filesTobeCollected(f);
            System.out.println("Found" + f);
        }
```

Here File[] fileEntry seems to have some limit as I push more directories using test.add("src/test/resources/obj") File[] fileEntry can't handle any more files. Is any alternative for File[] fileEntry incase of unlimited or unknown number of files?

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: Why do you have `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {`? This for loop executes exactly once; you may as well just remove it.

Comment: `Is any alternative for File[] fileEntry incase of unlimited or unknown number of files?` - usually you should use someting like `ArrayList` instead of raw arrays, but this is not the issue here since `listFiles();` already allocates an array with the proper size. Please post an [mcve] so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: is all good..thank you all for the quick response...my directory names were wrong. So function simply gave null pointer as it couldn't find the path..

Answer (score 3):

> Is any alternative for `File[] fileEntry` incase of unlimited or unknown number of files?

Yes, use `ArrayList<File>` wich will handle size automatically for you.

---

But this does not seem to be the problem because you know all the files you need to handle in the array creation so size is accurate `File[] fileEntry = folder.listFiles();`.

Remove this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
```

which seems useles... If problem remains, **post your stacktrace**

Answer (score 1):

As deeply I recognized you, you want to collect those files in one.

In my case first I would recommend to collect the file(s) path or file(s) and add those in an `ArrayList<File>`, secondary read those file(s) and collect in `ArrayList<byte[]>`, later if you want to make it a single file, Surely you can use an `ObjectOutputStream` class to write the `ArrayList<byte[]>` `Object` and certainly create a single `File`

**During this take care of File reading & writing bytes sizes don't crosses your Java Heap Space boundary.**